# Symfony 4.2 / Messenger - Is there a method to send to wildcard only unmatched items?

Tags: symfony, messenger

I use Messenger component in Symfony 4.2, and multiple routing for differents usages (SMS handler, mail handler, other usage) and I would  that wildcard in routing catch only Message that not match by others routes.

Here my messenger configuration

```
# config/packages/messenger.yaml
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            # DataSource for multiple transport
            amqp_mailer: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN_MAILER)%'
            amqp_sms: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN_SMS)%'
            amqp: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'

        routing:
            'App\Message\MailNotification': amqp_mailer
            'App\Message\SmsNotification': amqp_sms

            # All unmatched to global ? 
            '*': amqp
```

```
#.env
###> symfony/messenger ###
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f/messages
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN_MAILER=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f/mails
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN_SMS=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f/sms
###< symfony/messenger ###
```

I create three Message type and three handlers with the same logic for test purpose

Handlers:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Message\Handler;

use App\Message\SmsNotification;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Handler\MessageHandlerInterface;

class GlobalHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{

    public function __invoke(SmsNotification $message)
    {
        var_dump($message);
    }
}
```

Same for SmsHandler and MailerHandler

Messages:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Message;

class GlobalNotification {

    private $content;

    public function __construct(string $content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent(): string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }
}
```

Same logic for SmsNotification and MailNotification

And I dispatch 3 events in controller action:

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/messenger", name="app_front_main_messenger")
     * @param TraceableMessageBus|MessageBusInterface $bus
     * @return Response
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function messenger(MessageBusInterface $bus)
    {
        $bus->dispatch(new MailNotification('Mail '.date('H:i:s')));
        $bus->dispatch(new SmsNotification('Sms '.date('H:i:s')));
        $bus->dispatch(new GlobalNotification('Global '.date('H:i:s')));
        return $this->render('front/main/homepage.html.twig', []);
    }
```

Expected: 
SmsNotification only catch by SmsHandler, 
MailNotification only catch by MailerHandler, 
GlobalNotification only catch by GlobalHandler

Actual results:
GlobalHandler catch all Message

In RabbitMQ dashboard, I can see that messages queue received three message:
https://i.ibb.co/nf4g9Q9/Capture-d-e-cran-2019-04-15-a-11-09-37.png
(Sorry, not enough reputation to put the image directly)

How can I tell to Symfony to not send SmsNotification and MailNotification to '*' routing?
Or should I check in GlobalHandler not to process the received SmsNotification or MailNotification?